# My DatePicker doesn't have the SelectedDate properties in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I have problem with toolkit:DatePicker, there isn't SelectedDate Properties. I've tried to put

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

inside the XAML. How am I supposed to solve it. I'm using Windows Phone 8.

```
<grid>
<toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" Foreground="Gray" Header=""  Margin="0,364,10,362" Value="10/10/2010" ValueChanged="datePicker_ValueChanged"/>
</grid>
```

Comment: consider to replace wpf tag with silverlight. windows phone is based on *silverlight*, not wpf. That fact matter because, not all solution that works for wpf applicable for silverlight/wp. For example, silverlight/wp doesn't have `x:Static` markup extension.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` is static property so you can bind using `x:Static` markup extension like this:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

`sys` corresponds to System namespace where DateTime is declared.

---

I hope `StaticResource` exist in WP8. If yes above can be simulate like this as well:

```
<Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Grid.Resources>
     <sys:DateTime x:Key="CurrentDateTime"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <toolkit:DatePicker Value="{Binding Path=Now,
                        Source={StaticResource CurrentDateTime}, Mode=OneWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

PS - Define resource anywhere you feel like (I used Grid to depict to declare it somewhere in parent element only).

---

Last if above doesn't seem to work (ideally it should have), I would suggest to have *wrapper property in your DataContext class that will return Today's DateTime and bind with it*.

```
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

and bind directly with it:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Value="{Binding Path=CurrentDateTime, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have gotten more problems. It says that he type 'x:Static' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. and the tag 'Static' does not exist in XML Namespace.

Comment: I thought you was talking about `WPF` here since question was tagged with it. However, you can mimic `x:Static` as described in article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yl/archive/2009/07/22/x-type-and-x-static-in-silverlight.aspx).

Comment: I am! but i have no idea what happen in my WP8 XAML, i've tried many ways to solve this, but it seems like it has no solution. I've tried to use the x:Static but the namespace is missing, but when i find the solution, it says that Static is only for Silverlight. I am confused, please someone explain to me what happen? Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another workaround. See if that works for you.!!

Comment: Thanks you for helping but another problems revealed. When I try your latest solution, there's no problem with syntax. But the problem occurs when i try to run it. It redirect me to Break or Continue windows. Then i try to remove xmlns:sys from <Grid> because i have the same xmlns:sys up above. But the problem still exist, it's like runtime error or something.

Comment: It says that "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"

Comment: Click on `ViewDetails` of exception and post inner exception here.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know how. Because it's only pop up the Alert window with only have three buttons- `Break`, `Continue`, and `Ignore`. When i click `Break`, it refers to `InitializeComponent()` in `MainPage` Class. When i click `Continue`, it refers to `Debugger.Break()`. Then there's no way i could handle the error anymore. Please help.

Comment: Wrap `InitializeComponent()` inside try catch and when exception gets thrown it will be catch by your catch block and check for property `ex.InnerException` over there.

Comment: Or may be before that try this more verbose definition of binding- `{Binding Path=Now, Source={StaticResource CurrentDateTime}, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: I try the second one, but it just the same error. Then I try the first one you've told me, and it's only shows the blank page on my Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere else in your XAML. Try this in blank XAML and see if this works.

Comment: I think it is. Every time I run the emulator, it always pops the message up that says the code has been changed outside the editor, then it refers to `MainPage.xaml.cs.g` with `Inline DatePicker` or something. It's that connected with the problem?

Comment: Not sure since I haven't worked on Windows Phone 8. However, I updated with another approach. See if that helps.

Comment: Negative! It just didn't work. But thanks so much for helping with this mess.

Comment: After i modified my code the problem comes from the `<Grid.Resources>`. I have no idea what happen, but the error is gone when i remove it from the XAML. Any idea?

Comment: Third approach should have work though. Have you set `DataContext` on parent control to class where you have created this property?

Comment: No I haven't, could you tell me how?

Comment: I think you need to learn on XAML bindings before working on more complex scenarios. [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

By default the WP8 toolkit DatePicker shows current date as selected Date.
If you want to set any other date, you can set using `value` property of DatePicker.
If you want to retrieve the selected date, then you can use `DataPicker.Value` and cast it to your need.